# Electrical Equipments - Meter Bridge

Tags: electric-current

If in a meter Bridge we interchange the battery and galvanometer at the balance point. Will galvanometer show deflection? Although the answer is no, I'm not able understand the logic behind it, and I think answer should be yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the circuit diagram for the meter bridge (a Wheatstone bridge circuit), you will see that you can move around the branches containing the battery and the galvanometer until they switch positions, without changing any connections (Basically, 'pull out' the galvanometer branch and 'push in' the battery branch). Though these branches are geometrically distinct, they are equivalent electrically.

Comment: But if I interchange them, it wouldn't be a wheatstone bridge anymore as there is a source of charge within the system.

Comment: @AnmolVashishtha Both branches are equivalent.. so it doesn't matter which component you put where.. I can draw the same circuit with the galvanometer outside and the battery inside and electrically, nothing would change. All the currents flowing through all the components would still be the same. It just looks spatially different.